# Nonparametric confidence interval for the mean: Failure to reproduce formula from Zhou & Dinh (2005)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, mean, nonparametric, skewness

[Zhou & Dinh (2005)](https://academic.oup.com/biostatistics/article/6/2/187/242229?login=true) propose the following formula for a $(1 - \alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for the mean of one sample. The confidence interval is based on a transformation of the
$t$-statistic:

[image: Zhou1]

where $n$ is the sample size, $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, $S$ is the standard deviation and $\hat{\gamma}$ is an estimate of the population skewness.

Here is a numerical example: I drew 20 samples from an $\mathrm{N}(100, 225)$ distribution with $\bar{x} = 101.06, s = 17.08, \bar{\gamma} = 0.955$. Further, setting $\alpha = 0.05$ we have: $\zeta_{0.975}=\Phi(0.975) = 0.8352$ and $\zeta_{0.025} = \Phi(0.025) = 0.51$. The $95\%$ confidence interval evaluates to $(0.984;\;99.416)$.

I tried to implement these formulas but stumbled upon a problem: The coverage of these confidence intervals is nowhere near the nominal value.

**Where is the mistake?**

I find the usage of the standard normal CDF instead of the respective quantile function a bit suspect. When I changed $\zeta_{\alpha} = \Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$, the coverage is near the nominal value. The disadvantage is that the formulas potentially break down with small sample sizes because the argument in $T_{3}^{-1}$ below the cube root gets negative. Using the numbers from the example above, we have: $\zeta_{0.975}=\Phi^{-1}(0.975) = 1.96$ and $\zeta_{0.025} = \Phi^{-1}(0.025) = -1.96$. Thus, $T_{3}^{-1}(20^{-1/2}\times -1.96 = -0.438)=\left\{1+3\left(-0.438 - 20^{-1}\frac{1}{6}0.955\right)\right\}^{1/3} - 1=(-0.3387)^{1/3} - 1$

---

I conducted a small simulation study to check the coverage. At the normal, it's only around 9% instead of the nominal 95%. Here is the `R` code:

```
# The functions

skew <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  n/((n - 1)*(n - 2)) * sum(((x - mean(x))/(sd(x)))^3)
}

T3 <- function(x, n, gamma) {
  (1 + 3*(x - n^(-1)*(1/6)*gamma))^(1/3) - 1
}

ci_np <- function(x, alpha) {      
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  n <- length(x)
  z <- pnorm(c(1 - (alpha/2), alpha/2))
  gamma <- skew(x)      
  Tvals <- c(T3(n^(-1/2)*z[1], n, gamma), T3(n^(-1/2)*z[2], n, gamma))
  
  m - Tvals*s      
}

# The simulations

set.seed(142857)

n_sim <- 10000

res <- replicate(n_sim, {      
  x <- rnorm(100, 100, 15)  
  tmp <- ci_np(x, 0.05)  
  ifelse((tmp[1] <= 100) && (tmp[2] >= 100), 1, 0)      
})

mean(res)
[1] 0.0869
```

Comment: Visual inspection uncovers one obvious error: you have written `pnorm` instead of `qnorm`.  The more fundamental error is not performing unit testing of your functions: before you see whether a simulation gives expected results, you want to be *sure* that the helper functions `skew` and `T3` are calculating correctly and then you want to check `ci_np` against any published results.

Comment: @whuber The paper itself says to use `pnorm` if I'm not mistaken: $\zeta_{\alpha}=\Phi(\alpha)$, right? As I wrote: Coverage is indeed near nomial when using `qnorm`.

Comment: Yes, the paper does seem to say that (right after its formula $(2.5)$), but that's not believable. (Consider what the CI formula reduces to when no transformation is applied.)  It might have intended to write $\xi_\alpha=\Phi^{-1}(\alpha).$  However, the change in notation from "$z_\alpha$" to "$\xi_\alpha$" does worry me.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the confirmation, that's what I suspected. I think this pretty much clears up my confusion.